# image (blob/jpeg) from MySql database to html using GoLang

Tags: mysql, database, go, web, blob

I have started using Go lately, and right now developing an example ecommerce website and i want to make item cards with thumbnails but i can't find a way to get the images from my database to html templates inside  tags.

I'm using Go's native http server.

Every bit of help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to base64 the binary and add that to an image src attribute. not really a go question, so here is more info:

[How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)